# How to get substring in scala?

Tags: string, scala, substring

How do I get the substring for the string :

```
 "s3n://bucket/test/files/*/*"
```

I would like to get s3n://bucket/test/files alone. I tried the split :

`"s3n://bucket/test/files/*/*".split("/*/*")` but this gives me array of strings with each character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The argument to split is a regex and `/*/*` matches all the characters in your string. You need to escape `*`:

```
"s3n://bucket/test/files/*/*".split("/\\*/\\*")
```

An alternative to `split` in this case could be:

```
"s3n://bucket/test/files/*/*".stripSuffix("/*/*")
```

Answer (score 6):

A couple of options not using a regex.

Using `takeWhile` gives "s3n://bucket/test/files/" which includes the last slash.

```
scala> s.takeWhile(_ != '*')
res11: String = s3n://bucket/test/files/
```

Using `indexOf` to find the first "*" and taking one less character than that gives the output you specify.

```
scala> s.slice(0,s.indexOf("*") - 1)
res14: String = s3n://bucket/test/files
```